# Reverse Engineering SOT23-6 device marking 41Я0

Tags: mosfet

Hello Guys and thanks for having me!

I have a burned down SOT23-6 on a PCB (sennheiser AC1) with the device marking "41Я0".
Maybe one of you can tell me which component this is?
Photos:
[image]
[image]

What i found out:
*The cirquit path on which the component was soldered, had 4 short circuited pins on this component (Pin 1,2,5 and 6). This could mean that the component was a MOSFET as most MOSFETs in SOT23-6 Package have those pins short cirquited (e.g. Si3441BDV from Vishay)

thank you!

Comment: The links to your images is broken for me. Can you upload them to imgur and give the links in a comment. Somebody then can edit your question to replace the links.

Comment: I'm not signing in to anything to look at photos.

Comment: Hey guys! Sorry for that mistake, i thought i tried the dropbox link but maybe i was still logged in so i could see the files. Now here is the imgur link as wished: http://imgur.com/gallery/iRd0x

Comment: You've got bigger problems than that one component.  You need to replace the whole board, then understand what fried it so that you can avoid a repeat in the future.

Comment: Thanks for that useful and sophisticated hint. First, the client shortcuted the antenna output. thats why the component got fried. Second, why should i replace a whole board when only one component died. Dont get me wrong, i appreciate every information about my question but your answer did not match my question. I just would like to know what component the code "41Я0" is.  Just FYI: i allready replaced the component with a IRF5800 P-channel mosfet and it works. I`d just have a better conscience to know the origin data of the component. All the best, serviceGuy